# Switching from 32bit to 64bit results in Metadata not found?

Tags: c#, .net, build, 64-bit, configurationmanager

My solution contains a lot of project, when switching from AnyCPU(32bit) to x64 I get alot of Metadata file X could not be found?

To build all projects in x64 I use the Configuration Manager where I set it to release and x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the trouble is caused by references between projects where the project dependencies are not updated.  You can confirm them under Project -> Project Dependencies for each project giving trouble.